# can you help me with this error? [ERROR] setting file settings.gradle

Tags: javascript, titanium-sdk

I get this error when starting the application on android

```
[ERROR] [GRADLE] * Where:
[ERROR] [GRADLE] Settings file '/Users/programador1/Documents/apps/build/android/settings.gradle'
[ERROR] [GRADLE] 
[ERROR] [GRADLE] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [GRADLE] Could not compile settings file '/Users/programador1/Documents/apps/build/android/settings.gradle'.
[ERROR] [GRADLE] > startup failed:
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 64
```

Titanium version 11.1.GA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the wrong Java version. Please use version 16 and check the compatibility list at https://titaniumsdk.com/guide/Titanium_SDK/Titanium_SDK_Getting_Started/Installation_and_Configuration/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix/#java-development-kit

Comment: My java versions are 20, 17, 16

Comment: yes, 64 should be java 20. So you'll need to make 16 your default that comes up when you run `java --version`. There is only one active version. Your `JAVA_HOME` env variable should point to version 16. There is already a pull request for Java 20 support but it is not included in the SDK yet